# for loop display undesired result php

Tags: php, arrays, json, for-loop

The output of the result for the php i created is like this :

> {"result":[{"day":"1","count":"0"}]}{"result":[{"day":"2","count":"0"}]}....

but i want the output of the result :

> {"result":[{"day":"1","count":"0"},{"day":"2","count":"0"}...]

The following is my php code:

```
<?php

 define('HOST','xx');
 define('USER','xx');
 define('PASS','xx');
 define('DB','xx');


 //$month = $_POST['month'];
 //$year = $_POST['year'];

 $month = 10;
 $year=2016;


 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

 $sql = "select count(entryID) from Entry where
      EXTRACT(DAY FROM(entryTime)) = '$day'  AND
      EXTRACT(MONTH FROM(entryTime)) = '$month' AND 
      EXTRACT(YEAR FROM(entryTime))= '$year'";

 for($day =1 ; $day<31 ; $day++)
 {
 $day2 = (string)$day;
 $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 $result = array();
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
 array_push($result,
 array('day' =>$day2,
    'count' => $row[0]
 ));

 }

 }
 echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));


 mysqli_close($con);

 ?>
```

Asking for help..

Comment: Is it correct that you set `$result = array();` in the for loop? That does not make sense to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First mistake: You will **always** get a count of `0` for every query you execute because your string `$sql` contains an undefined variable `$day` during its definition.

Second mistake: You are re-declaring `$result` inside your loop.

Solution:

```
 $result = array();
 for ($day=1 ; $day<31 ; $day++) {
     $sql = "select count(entryID) from Entry where
         EXTRACT(DAY FROM(entryTime)) = '$day'  AND
         EXTRACT(MONTH FROM(entryTime)) = '$month' AND 
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM(entryTime))= '$year'";
     $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

     $day2 = (string)$day;
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
         array_push($result,
         array('day' =>$day2,
            'count' => $row[0]
         ));
     }
 }
 echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
```

Comment: ya. i just found out my count always return 0; your code is working! thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with result = array() in the for loop, with each iteration you're creating the result array again. try to define the array before the loop.
and then merge each result into the single result array.

ps: sorry that i can't share a corrected code, since i've limited abilities right now, but i guess the clue will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take the `$result=array()` off the for loop as it's not making any sense at all. Try removing it from there and placing it before the for-loop

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `$result = array();` before the `for-loop`. You just reinitialized `$result` every iteration of the `for-loop`:

```
$result = array();

for($day =1 ; $day<31 ; $day++) {

    $day2 = (string)$day;
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        array_push($result,
        array('day' =>$day2,
              'count' => $row[0]
        ));

    }
}
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
```